# Efficient way to find the i-th size in a BST

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, runtime-analysis

Given the following definition of binary search tree:

$$\text{size}(t)=\cases{0\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad t=\text{ null}\\
1+\text{size(t.left)+size(t.right)}\qquad\text{otherwise}}$$

for each vertex in the tree t.size contain the size of it's subtree

> Write an algorithm  selection(T,i) that gets a Tree with size at each vertex and return the $i-$th smallest/largest size in the tree

---

*Attempt:*

I discovered that the size of a vertex is the number of vertices that there are in the specific root:

e.g:

```
                              V_1
                             /   \
                           V_2    V_3
                           /      / \
                         V_4     V_5 V_6
```

The size of $V_4,V_5,V_6$ is: $1+0=1$

The size of $V_2$ is: $1+1=2$

The size of $V_3$ is: $1+1+1=3$

The size of $V_1$ is: $1+3+2=6$

Now to scan all vertices in the tree using preorder or postorder and to find the $i-th$ size, running time $O(|V|)$,

I am looking for something more efficient.

Comment: Yes, this is the input, there is no restrictions on additional memory

Comment: In your example, is `2` the second weight or the fourth?

Comment: '2' is the second size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Please check the problem statement: having sub-tree sizes at each vertex available in constant time is very useful to find the $i$−th smallest/largest *element/key* (with $2$ being the 3rd smallest element in $1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4$).)

For finding the $i$−th largest size, notice the tree to be a max-heap with respect to sub-tree sizes.
In search of the $i$−th smallest size, assume that the tree is perfectly balanced but for the path to *one* leaf, which is longer by *i* ($∄j: i = 2^j-1$). Before encountering that path/vertex, all sizes no larger than *i* will have been of the form ($2^j-1$). As you don't know if and where such a path/vertex exists, you will have to visit on the order of all *n* vertices.
*Unless* you find a way to know the $i$−th size among $Ο(n)$ candidates faster, this will be $Ω(n \log(i))$ in $Ο(i)$ space. (This depends on how much additional memory can be used, e.g., with $Ο(n)$ memory, you can do a counting sort of sizes encountered in $Ο(n)$ time.)

Run-time can be reduced by properly bounding the search:
Every non-empty tree will contain at least one leaf, so if *i* is $1$, return $1$.
For $1 < i$, keep track of the highest size `s` such that every size up to `s` is known to have been encountered. When `s` reaches $i$, return that. Never descend from vertices with *size* no greater than `s`.

Comment: Could you explain why would you do that? Isn't it just worse than the obvious $O(n)$ solution?

Comment: @quicksort: Please sketch `the obvious O(n) solution`.

Comment: Collect the weights into an array. Median of medians.

Comment: @quicksort: `Median of medians` quickselect, rather. (While that's the `Unless you find a way to know the i−th size among O(n) candidates faster` part,) somehow, I was under the impression that $O(\log n)$ memory wasn't admissible.

Comment: (Does quickselect support $i$-th _unique_ value?) (Then again, you could use a counting sort in $O(n)$ space.)